# Cannot see Request Message sent from Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have followed the Facebook android Send Requests dialog tutorial
My Friends do receive the requests however they cannot see the message I associated with the request.

e.g. 
`params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");`

where is this message supposed to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = extras.getString("message");
```